# Raw Entity Framework

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-6

Estoy tratando de llamar una consulta SQL Server desde Raw

```
var result = context.Database.SqlQuery<UniversalExtend>("SELECT distinct(PC.ProductoCatalogoId)," +
                                                                    " P.Nombre + ' ' + PL.Product + ' ' + E.Nombre + ' ' + O.NombreOpcion AS Descripcion, PC.PrecioVenta" +
                                                                    " FROM ProductoCatalogos AS PC" +
                                                                    " INNER JOIN Productos AS P ON PC.ProductoId = P.ProductoId" +
                                                                    " INNER JOIN EspecificacionCatalogos AS EC ON PC.ProductoCatalogoId = EC.ProductoCatalogoId" +
                                                                    " INNER JOIN EspecificacionProductos AS EP ON EC.EspecificacionProductoId = EP.EspecificacionProductoId" +
                                                                    " INNER JOIN Especificaciones AS E ON EP.EspecificacionId = E.EspecificacionId" +
                                                                    " AND E.EspecificacionId = @colorId",
                new SqlParameter("@colorId", colorId) +
                " INNER JOIN Opciones AS O ON EC.OpcionId = O.OpcionId" +
                " CROSS APPLY(" +
                " SELECT E.Nombre + ' ' + O.NombreOpcion AS 'Product'" +
                " FROM ProductoCatalogos AS PC" +
                " INNER JOIN Productos AS P ON PC.ProductoId = P.ProductoId" +
                " INNER JOIN EspecificacionCatalogos AS EC ON PC.ProductoCatalogoId = EC.ProductoCatalogoId" +
                " INNER JOIN EspecificacionProductos AS EP ON EC.EspecificacionProductoId = EP.EspecificacionProductoId" +
                " INNER JOIN Especificaciones AS E ON EP.EspecificacionId = E.EspecificacionId" +
                " AND E.EspecificacionId = @tallaId", new SqlParameter("@tallaId", tallaId) +
                                                      " INNER JOIN Opciones AS O ON EC.OpcionId = O.OpcionId" +
                                                      " ) PL" +
                                                      " WHERE P.Nombre LIKE '%' + @valor + '%'",
                new SqlParameter("@valor", valor)).ToList();
```

El error es el siguiente:

> When executing a command, parameters must be exclusively database parameters or values.

Comment: Yo no suelo usar EF, pero diría que el primer parámetro de SqlQuery es la consulta en si, y todos los parámetros van a continuación, no por en medio. Intenta poner los `new SqlParameter` al final

Comment: como dice Pikoh no puedes hacer ese tipo de interpolación con los parámetros

Comment: @Pikoh Tu recomendación fue la solución a mi problema muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puede solucionar mi problema gracias a la recomendación de @Pikoh

```
var result = context.Database.SqlQuery<UniversalExtend>("SELECT distinct(PC.ProductoCatalogoId)," +
                                                                    " P.Nombre + ' ' + PL.Product + ' ' + E.Nombre + ' ' + O.NombreOpcion AS Descripcion, PC.PrecioVenta" +
                                                                    " FROM ProductoCatalogos AS PC" +
                                                                    " INNER JOIN Productos AS P ON PC.ProductoId = P.ProductoId" +
                                                                    " INNER JOIN EspecificacionCatalogos AS EC ON PC.ProductoCatalogoId = EC.ProductoCatalogoId" +
                                                                    " INNER JOIN EspecificacionProductos AS EP ON EC.EspecificacionProductoId = EP.EspecificacionProductoId" +
                                                                    " INNER JOIN Especificaciones AS E ON EP.EspecificacionId = E.EspecificacionId" +
                                                                    " AND E.EspecificacionId = @colorId" +
                                                                    " INNER JOIN Opciones AS O ON EC.OpcionId = O.OpcionId" +
                                                                    " CROSS APPLY(" +
                                                                    " SELECT E.Nombre + ' ' + O.NombreOpcion AS 'Product'" +
                                                                    " FROM ProductoCatalogos AS PC" +
                                                                    " INNER JOIN Productos AS P ON PC.ProductoId = P.ProductoId" +
                                                                    " INNER JOIN EspecificacionCatalogos AS EC ON PC.ProductoCatalogoId = EC.ProductoCatalogoId" +
                                                                    " INNER JOIN EspecificacionProductos AS EP ON EC.EspecificacionProductoId = EP.EspecificacionProductoId" +
                                                                    " INNER JOIN Especificaciones AS E ON EP.EspecificacionId = E.EspecificacionId" +
                                                                    " AND E.EspecificacionId = @tallaId" +
                                                                    " INNER JOIN Opciones AS O ON EC.OpcionId = O.OpcionId" +
                                                                    " ) PL" +
                                                                    " WHERE P.Nombre LIKE '%' + @valor + '%'",
                new SqlParameter("@colorId", colorId), new SqlParameter("@tallaId", tallaId),
                new SqlParameter("@valor", valor)).ToList();
```

Saludos!